# Inserting image in a td using jquery function html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony

I am trying to insert an image into a td row with html() JQuery function (see http://jsfiddle.net/R5q68/).

The problem is that the image is not displayed. When I analyse my td, it seems that there is no slash to close the img tag.

I am using symfony2 and assets, that's why my image link is like that.

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/sciforumversion2/images/design/new/submission/element_up.png') }}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution: I had to create a global JavaScript varialble with the image path:

```
<script>
    var arrow_down = "{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/images/menu_down.png') }}";
</script>
```

And with this path, I was able to set the image asset:

```
goes_down_td.html('<img src="'+arrow_down+'"/>');
```

And it is done. Enjoy.

Comment: Isn't it what I suggested in my answer ?

Comment: @dystroy, not at all, where are you talking about the global variable? Or maybe I heven't understood your answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can't build such a string using jQuery because jQUery is executed client-side while symfony2 is executed server-side.

The string `"{{ asset('bundles/scif..."` needs to be interpreted by the server but that's too late when you're executing jQuery. You can't build the asset template client side.

What you can do is insert some standard HTML :

```
 td.html('<img src=http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/tartare-saumon-creme-salade-harengs-pommes-de-terre-800.jpg">');​
```

But if you build your string in one simple var as

```
var image_src = "{{asset('bundles/sciforumversion2/images/design/new/submission/element_up.png')}}";

td.html('<img src="'+image_src+'">');
```

AND you have symfony executed (ie, not doing this in jsfiddle) then it should work.

Comment: Thank you, interesting point. So, how could I then display an image there. Put it as hidden and then change visibility?

Comment: @jenson-button-event Sorry?

Comment: @dystroy, But your solution with js variable is exactly what I am doing no?

Comment: @Milos : no, it's not the same. As you cut the asset template, it can't be interpreted by symfony2.

Comment: @dystroy, I am not following you. If I understand, using the last paragraph of your answer (by creating image_src and then using td.html(...)) it should work right?

Comment: The point is that your asset template must not be cut in the page, because symfony2 can only interpret a non cut template.

Comment: @jenson-button-event ad-free : http://dystroy.org/re7210/ (this comment will probably self destruct as it's off-topic)

Comment: @dystroy, but how am I cutting the template? By dividing the image path in more than one uniaue string? I tryed with your image_src but stil the same problem

Comment: @Milos did you try on your server ? This can't work in a fiddle as symfony must interpret the page.

Comment: I am trying in my project with a real symfony2 project. I think the problem is with the path. There are single or double quotes missing because when I am checking the html of the td, I am getting somethink like: `<img element_up.png")}}"="" submission="" new="" design="" images="" sciforumversion2="" bundles="" src="{{asset(">`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20764/discussion-between-milos-and-dystroy)

Answer (score -1):

check ur image path 
        and try this:

```
     var td = $('#test');
    img_src= '<img src="../bundles/sciforumversion2/images/design/new/submission/element_up.png" id="td_img" />;
    td.innerhtml(img_src);
```